# package 'keras' successfully installed, but can't be loaded?

Tags: r, keras

I tried to installed `keras` on win10 + Rstudio 1.2, it was successfully installed, but can't be loaded. 
Have tried to uninsatll, and re-install, but the error insists.

Please advise.

```
> install.packages("keras")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/eric1/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
trying URL 'https://mran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2018-08-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/keras_2.1.6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2340096 bytes (2.2 MB)
downloaded 2.2 MB

package ‘keras’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\eric1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaynDb0\downloaded_packages


> library(keras)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘keras’ in rbind(info, getNamespaceInfo(env, "S3methods")):
 number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

and the traceback is

```
> traceback()
6: stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
5: value[[3L]](cond)
4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
3: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
2: tryCatch({
       attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
       ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
       env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)
   }, error = function(e) {
       P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
           paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
       else ""
       msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
           sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
       if (logical.return) 
           message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
       else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
   })
1: library(keras)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the hint from this post, I checked the `reticulate`, and got the same error message which i am sure it was good. So I decided the root was Python and Anaconda.
I reinstalled python and anaconda, and solved the issue.

Just make a note and hopefully it may help those who are as rooky as I am.

[package or namespace load failed for ‘keras’ #268](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/268?fbclid=IwAR2oeIXvakg1pVRG_KcVb6dEAYBc_G-QZCDIQUEQMg7evY9WDXWchwwRkvU)